# Copy Row to a position dependent on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched all over but have yet to find someone who has been able to asnwer this.

I'm in the process of trying to create a macro to streamline requesting days off, so to help modernize the payroll sheet while still allowing it to be compatible with the legacy system.

I want to have this sheet be the input:
[image]

And then the macro (activated from a button click)

would copy that data, find the associated employee, then paste to fit with the legacy system as shown below:

[image]

So the macro would match the respective employee of each entry, and paste the respective entry to the next entry in the log of the employee. Any idea of how to go about this?

I am completely lost and not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could show your code and ask a concrete question about it? Because there's no problem in VBA to copy-paste any Range of Cells (or it's values, or it's formats etc.) with any logical conditions you need. MSDN has a clear example: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy

Comment: Is there a way to do an index-match style paste, rather than the if "Employee 1" then. else "Employee 2" then..  else"Employee 3" then...

Comment: Of course. Use For-Next loop with any conditions and indexes you want. E.g. For i = 1 To lastRow: Next i. And your condition inside a loop will be like: If Cells(i, 1).Value Then. It will iterate all rows in a table by first column. LastRow should be a result of Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row expression or any other digit value for last iterated row.